# Python testing properties using partial

Tags: python, unit-testing, functional-programming, mocking

I have a mock object for following class

```
class Book(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self._counter = 1

    @property
    def counter(self):
        _, self._counter = self._counter, self._counter + 1 
        return _
```

the class `Book` have following Mock object

```
book = Mock(spec = Book, self._counter = 1)
```

if counter is not a property I could have written test as such

```
def test_counter(self):
    book.counter = partial(Book.counter, book)
    self.assertNotEquals(book.counter(), book.counter())
```

however since it is a property, the above strategy won't work, can you suggest a good way to write test for the property given I have to use Mock object for Book class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def test_counter(self):
    book.counter = partial(Book.counter.fget, book)
    self.assertNotEquals(book.counter(), book.counter())
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer a little bit.

Comment: Actually the `@property` decorator returns a property object which has a fget function to actually run the underlying function on which decorator was applied